# load two dll with same name in one project C++

Tags: c++

I need to load two dll in one project. Two dll have same name. The implementation inside the dll is different. I have two classes in my project. One class consume one dll and other class consume other dll. and both class are used in sequence in project.

Comment: why can't you rename the dlls?

Comment: And what does that mean "I need to load both the dll same time" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could we have 2 DLLs with the same name being loaded in one process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341010/could-we-have-2-dlls-with-the-same-name-being-loaded-in-one-process)

Comment: @EdChum Those are third party DLL.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious if you are having two dll with same name they are at different locations. So you can configure the `lpFileName` to include the path.

Besides you can also have different version number to create a differentiation between the 2 dll.

For more information you can visit following links

[Implicit way](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/b3eaa07f-7f92-4693-8aa1-b8fee0b92d2f/)

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28VS.85%29.aspx)